# How to remove Google account on Chrome?

Tags: google-account, chrome-for-android, google

My boyfriend needed to use my phone to access his email. Since logging in his account remains the default user whenever I open Chrome and Google search. I have tried deleting my device on his account in under active devices. I have tried going into Chrome settings but there is no option to remove the account!

Comment: Go to chrome>settings tap on account then sign out. Does that works?

Comment: Go to settings>App>Chrome>storage, and clear cache and data(clear all). Open Chrome again, step 1. Accept and continue to start, 2. enable/disable data saver, 3. ask about Google account, to skip, select 'not now'.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that your boyfriend's account is opened only in chrome ?
Well i think it's not.

The problem is not with the chrome if i am getting your problem. 
Here the person adds his account to your *Google Services* and your device is currently using it as its primary account. So, it is auto logging in as default account in chrome.

If you want to check:
Open *Gmail app* look for the account signed in already by touching 3 lines on the upper left of the screen, there must be showing your bfs account.

So now, you have to remove this account from your device. Follow these steps:

1. Open Settings-Account-Google
2. Now click the account you want to remove and touch 3 dots on the upper right corner of the screen and choose *remove account*.

It's done.

However, what you have did by removing your device from his 'my activities' tab.
This will only unlink your device from his Google account that means if you will try to sign in it may need to go through verification for signing in next time. As your device is now unknown/new for this particular Google account.

Answer (score 1):

Just hit "log out" and it'll log out of all of them. Then when you hover over it, it will finally have the "remove" option.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove his account from the phone  (Android), follow this steps:

1. Go to **Settings → Account → Google**
2. Then tap on his E-mail/ID , you can see the more menu on right top corner, tap on it
3. It will show two options **Sync now** and **Remove account**
4. Tap on **Remove account** option
5. Done

Answer (score 0):

If you have to remove account from chrome browser then open the browser and click on settings, then there is account on top tap on it, it will take you to next page from there you can remove, add or change account. 
Second way is Goto Settings>Scroll down to **Accounts (Portion)**>Tap on Google, there you will see a settings icon(3 vertical dots icon) on top right corner click on that and tap on remove account. 
Third way is Goto Settings>Apps>Chrome>Tap on **Manage space/Storage**>And then clear data from there. Hope it works....

Answer (score 0):

In the Chrome browser...If it takes you to your Gmail account as saying signed in by your email id ...don't worry press the upper left button which have three horizontal lines ..It will show your email id in upper corner.  click on it. Then it will go to "choose google account " page sign out from your account . After signing out if you want to remove your account you can. remove your account and add another account.